# Take variable from cs and use it in xaml (uwp)

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp

How can I use the value of a C# string in a XAML file?

Here the part of my code:
**CS file**:

```
public sealed partial class SomePage : Page
    {

        public SomePage ()
        {
            AppVersion = "some text" + XDocument.Load ("WMAppManifest.xml").Root.Element ("App").Attribute ("Version").Value.ToString();
            this.InitializeComponent ();

        }

        public string AppVersion{get; set;}
```

**XAML file:**

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
     EntranceNavigationTransitionInfo.IsTargetElement="True">
        <StackPanel>
             <TextBlock x:Name="VersionTextBlock" Text="{Binding ElementName=VersionTextBlock, FallbackValue= AppVersion}"/>
```

Comment: The first link with the binding seems to be the correct answer, can you show us some code? Otherwise we don't know if you are using it wrong.

Comment: Sorry but asking how to do something so vague is really not the best way to get an answer, as mentioned, share some code that you are trying or else be more specific in your question.

Comment: What you want do to exactly? Is binding a field dynamically? Static? Into a some type of list element? Into a TextBlock? You should specify more your question and show some code.

Comment: here is some code. I want to show version of the app. I think I'm mistake is in `Text="{Binding ElementName=VersionTextBlock, FallbackValue= AppVersion}"` am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your binding is referencing the `TextBlock`, which isn't where your `AppVersion` is. Since `Appversion` is a property on the `Page`, you can use compile-time binding as follows:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind AppVersion}"/>
```

Dynamic bindings, on the other hand, are relative to the `DataContext` of the `Page`, meaning if you want to do this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding AppVersion}"/>
```

...you'd have to set `Page`s `DataContext` to some object that has a property named `AppVersion`, e.g.,

```
public SomePage ()
{
    AppVersion = "some text" + ...;
    InitializeComponent ();
    DataContext = this; // More common is to have a separate viewmodel class, though.
}
```

Comment: That's working, thanks!